# Let $x$ be an element in a group $G$. Assume that the order of $x$ is $m$, and also that $x^n = e$. Prove that $m \mid n$.

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

> Let *x* be an element in a group $G$. Assume that the order of *x* is *m*, and also that $x^n = e$ (identity element). Prove that $m \mid n$.

So what I am thinking is that the order of an element is the smallest positive integer $m$ such that $x^m = e$.

There are other integers that satisfy this, but $m$ is the smallest. So $n \geq m$ but also has to be a multiple of $m$. Thus $m \mid n$ in either case.

Is there an intermediate step between this assertion? I more or less just described the idea instead of a formal proof.

Thank you for any and all help.

Comment: Proof by contradiction - if $m\nmid n$, then $n=mq+r$ for some $0<r<m$ and then $x^{r}=e$.

Comment: Im sorry I'm still confused, how is $x^r$ = e a contradiction to m ∤ n ?

Comment: @C.Math It is a contradiction because the order of $x$ is $m$ but $0<r<m$. The order by definition is the least positive integer such that $x^m=e$.

Comment: Ah okay that makes perfect sense! Thank you much!

Comment: "***So n≥m but also has to be a multiple of m.***" Bingo! Explain why this must be so.  Why can't $km < n < (k+1)m$ be such that $x^n = e$?  That is the essential and critical step of the proof.  Prove that and you are done.  State it without verification and you haven't done a damned thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We combine the fact that $m$ is the order of $x \in G$ with the division algorithm to proceed as follows:

Since $m$ is the order of $x$, it is the smallest positive integer with

$x^m = e; \tag 1$

now use the division algorithm to write

$n = mq + r, \; 0 \le r < m; \tag 2$

then

$x^{mq} = (x^m)^q = e^q = e, \tag 3$

so

$x^r = ex^r = x^{mq}x^r = x^{mq + r} = x^n = e; \tag 4$

if $r \ne 0$, this contradicts the assumption that $m$ is the smallest positive integer such that (1) binds.  Thus $r = 0$, $n = mq$, and

$m \mid n. \tag 5$